# How can I update IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 11.0 on Mac OS X. I know it has an update 11.0.1. 
But when I used <kbd>Check for update</kbd>, it said I am already running the latest version.

Please tell me how can I upgrade to version 11.0.1?

Thank you.

Comment: @Kristian: The correct questions would be "Have you tried turning it off and on again" :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you have a connection problem or your proxy/firewall blocks IDEA access to the site where it checks for updates.

I've tried it on my Mac and Windows machines and it works fine:
[image: Mac Update]

In any case, you can just [download and install](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) the complete version from .dmg file. Your license, settings and plugins will be preserved and the old version can be moved to Trash.

Comment: I can't agree that this answers the issue.  On the recent IDEA update, I have that dialogue.  On this linux machine, software is _owned_ by a non-login user.  Users can log-on and run software but not '_change_' it.  Short story, using *root* to run IDEA GUI and click update does NOT work.  I was forced to use `sudo` to `chown` the IDEA directories and then use the gui to `update` the IDE.  That only works IF you have privilege.  I do Not want a software '_owner_' user and group to have privileges.  Especially a tool like an IDEA with all kinds of _goodies_ in there.  Poor show.

Comment: @will This actually answers the issue perfectly. The poor show seems to be with your linux machine and it's unnecessarily complex and asinine management scheme. If a _developer_ does not have full control over the management of their _development_ machine, the development process is broken. Full stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check for updates:

Settings (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S`) > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates > `Check for Updates...`

You will get a notification asking you to restart the IDE to apply the update once it is complete, but you can still use the IDE while the update is being downloaded and there is no automatic restart.

As of 2023, automatic Downloads require the separate [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=toolbox_app_in_IDE_updatewindow&utm_content=we_recommend) from JetBrains.

Answer (score -2):

Open intellij-idea -> go to top menu bar  -> Help -> Check for Updates